# Anyone know why my reflection is appearing noisy/weird

Tags: rendering, texturing, edit-mode, normal-map

I am trying to create a scene where the reflection of the pumpkin and the lights can be seen in the floors surface, but for some reason when I render it goes weird and goes really noisy. Is there a setting I can change to fix this, as I want a realistic reflection. It even happened like this with the bump map on the pumpkins surface.

It looks like this.
[image]

Any help would be great thanks!

Comment: [How to upload an image to a post](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/75491/how-to-upload-an-image-to-a-post)

Comment: Related: [Do EEVEE samples have any effect when rendering?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/q/163189/78972)

Answer (score 2):

Without looking at the nodes for the floor it's hard to be sure, but it looks like you gave the floor material a little bit of Roughness, which creates noise that becomes "blotchy" when the Denoiser tries to fix it.

Options you can try:

- Set **Roughness** to zero (unless you really really wanted it)
- Increase the **samples** of your render (if you can wait)
- Stop using the built-in denoiser and use the compositor **Denoiser** instead (if you can't wait AND need the roughness to stay the way it is)

Comment: Thanks for the help I will try this, much appreciated!

Comment: Let us know if it worked!

Comment: It worked thanks mate!

Comment: @MarkByford Awesome!